# expand chars with special meaning in bash here-string

Tags: bash

Code goes below:

```
#!/bin/bash

wd1="hello"
wd2="world"

cat >> log.txt <<<"$wd1\t$wd2\n\n"
```

When I run the above script, `'\t','\n'` were not expanded at all. So I altered it to this:

```
cat >> log.txt <<<$(echo -e "$wd1\t$wd2\n\n")
```

But `'\t','\n'` are still not expanded. Why?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a heredoc which would be *much more readable* than a lot of `\t` and `\n`s?

Comment: @MichałGórny, well, I just want to find out why can't I do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `info bash`:

```
3.6.7 Here Strings
------------------

A variant of here documents, the format is:
     <<< WORD

   The WORD is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard
input.
```

1. `<<<"$wd1\t$wd2\n\n"` is subject to bash expansions but there is no standard expansion for `\t` or `\n`. That's why it doesn't happen.
2. `<<<$(echo -e "$wd1\t$wd2\n\n")` doesn't work because it is unquoted. `echo` outputs the special characters but then bash does field splitting and they got replaced by spaces.

You just need to quote it:

```
cat >> log.txt <<<"$(echo -e "$wd1\t$wd2\n\n")"
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash supports yet another kind of quoting that does expand certain escaped characters:

```
word=$'foo\nbar'
echo "$word"
```

Unfortunately, such quoted strings don't undergo parameter expansion:

```
word=$'$w1'
echo "$word"
```

If you are using bash 4 or later, you can use `printf` to set the value of a variable:

```
printf -v word "$wd1\t$wd2\n\n"
cat >> log.txt <<<"$word"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use (no here string):

```
echo -e "$wd1\t$wd2\n\n" >> log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
cat >> log.txt <(echo -e "$wd1\t$wd2\n\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

As @chepner pointed out, that type of special character is expanded inside `$' ... '`, and since you can switch quoting style within a single shell "word", you can do something like this:

```
cat >>log.txt <<<"$wd1"$'\t'"$wd2"$'\n\n'
```

Rather ugly, but it works. Another possibility is to put the special characters in variables, then use variable expansion for everything:

```
tab=$'\t'
nl=$'\n'

cat >>log.txt <<<"$wd1$tab$wd2$nl$nl"
```